# Mac + Netbeans C++ OpenGL problem

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, netbeans

I am trying to develop OpenGL programs with C++ on Mac using Netbeans, and there are some compilation errors:

**"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk dist/Release/GNU-MacOSX/sdl_test
mkdir -p build/Release/GNU-MacOSX
rm -f build/Release/GNU-MacOSX/main.o.d
g++    -c -O2 -MMD -MP -MF build/Release/GNU-MacOSX/main.o.d -o build/Release/GNU-MacOSX/main.o main.cpp
main.cpp:9:41: warning: OpenGL.framework/Headers/gl.h: No such file or directory**

my code is as simple as this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <OpenGL.framework/Headers/gl.h>

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

the compiler cannot find OpenGL header file even if I have added the including path and lib file in the project settings. This is really confusing..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your project properties go to `C++ Compiler`. Under `Include Directories` add `/System/Library/Frameworks`. Under `Linker` at the bottom under `Additional Options` add `-framework OpenGL`.

Change your include directive to `#include <OpenGL/gl.h>`

Now you should be able to compile your program. But I seem to be missing something, because I get a segmentation fault, when I call `glGetString`...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const GLubyte* version = glGetString(GL_VERSION); // segmentation fault

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're missing the creation of a OpenGL context, you can't call GL functions without one.

Comment: Hey bjoernz, it works finally! But I have several questions here: 1. I can understand add "/System/Library/Frameworks" to "Include Directory", but why can I directly include "<OpenGL/gl.h>" then? The path name should be "OpenGL.framework/headers/gl.h".. 2. This method does not provide a lib file hint to the linker, how can the linker find the lib file though?

Comment: Apple introduced the `-framework` option, which turns `<OpenGL/gl.h>` into the correct path behind the scenes. It also provides the linker with the necessary information. You can read a bit more about that topic on http://developer.apple.com/tools/gcc_overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler can't Find the referenced header file in it's search path.  Try to find the file manually on your hard disk, then ensure your compiler has that location in it's search path.